# why pcap_setfilter did not take effect

Tags: pcap, libpcap

I'm using libpcap as lib to write a C program for catching up coming IPs.
my code snippet as following:

```
struct bpf_program filter;
pcap_compile(pcap_handle, &filter, "icmp[icmptype]=0 and '(dst 16.11.26.100 or dst 16.11.27.100)'", 1, 0);
pcap_setfilter(pcap_handle, &filter);
```

But it didn't work, I still could see other dest Ips rather than only the above two Ips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check for errors from library routine calls.  If you'd checked for errors from `pcap_compile()`, you would have seen that the compile failed (due to the single quotes, although the error message would probably just be "syntax error").

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem, the right answer is here:

```
"icmp[icmptype]=0 and (dst 16.11.26.100 or dst 16.11.27.100)"
```

Just removed the single quota.